# What would be the better option to implement Employee class?

Tags: c++, vector

How do I find `Staffs` and `Manager` for a given employee? Here is my class definition:

```
class Employee
{
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    vector<Employee> boss;
    vector<Employee> staffs;

public:
    void addStaff(Employee e)
    {
        staffs.push_back(e);
    }

    void setBoss(Employee e)
    {
        boss.push_back(e);
    }

    Employee getManager()
    {
        vector<Employee>::iterator itr;
        itr = boss.begin();
        return (*itr);
    }
};
```

To find the staffs, I am iterating through the `staffs` vector. What would be better way to implement this? For each employee there would be one `Manager`. So using `vector` for the boss/manager is not a good option, right?

Comment: Normally I find it better to separate things into various categories. Manager, Boss and Staff should be in their own class, with a reference or multiple references to their own Manager, Boss or other Staffs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: But without a pretty standard OOP design in his classes it will all just be one convoluted mess when he wants to achieve relationships like one Manager per staff.

Comment: Your design is storing the employees as components of an employee. That can't work. Employees can be components of "company" not other employee. Use pointers or smart pointers to other employees to form relations between them inside a company.

Comment: use `map<int,Employee>` for boss & staffs, use id as the key, and add boss_id to each Employee, this way you create some kind of a tree. you need to add boss_id when adding a worker, or use `boss_id=0` for no boss if 0 is not valid id.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the code here won't compile because you are trying to use a class inside itself the issue here really seems to be a design flaw more than anything else (you might be able to fix the immediate problem by using a pointer instead but I would suggest you reconsider your design first).
The relationship between various employees is not an attribute of the employee so I would hesitate to store it as a member of the class. If I did for some reason go with the design you have here and store the relationships between employees in the employee class then I wouldn't store copies of the employee objects by value. Storing copies by value leads to problems keeping data synchronized and consistent (not to mention is a very poor use of space if there are a large number of relations between employees). It would be better to use something like smart pointers to the employee objects.

Or you could change your design. If each employee can have a unique id you might do better to store the relations outside of the employee class. There's a few data structures that you could use to do that, essentially you have some graphs that show the relations where the nodes are employees and the edges are the relations. You would either use smart pointers there or store the unique key that represents the employees.